# SQL Server CE runtime in C# project?

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce, merge-module

I have an app using SQL Server Compact Edition. So I need the runtime to be on all the machines. I've been looking for the merge modules for the runtime however I've had no luck there.

Is there a way to bring the runtime into the app itself? And in so doing not not requiring the user to install the runtime?

Or is there a way of extracting the modules from the msi and loading them into my installer?

I am using Visual Studio 2012. And playing around with a few installer creators like Create install free. As a side, does anyone have a good freeware installer creator?

Any help would be great,

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can include the SQL Server Compact DLL files with your app, so you do not need to install anything in addition to your app - see my blog for long, detailed description - which SQL Server Compact version do you use?

Comment: I'm currently using compact 4.0.

Comment: @ErikEj what is your blogname?

Comment: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html and